# Using tooltip with listline plot

Tags: plotting, tooltip

I'm trying generate a simlilar graph to the one shown at [https://ourworldindata.org/co2/country/greece?country=~GRC](https://ourworldindata.org/co2/country/greece?country=%7EGRC)

[image]

On this graph, when you hover over a data point, the information is displayed and a vertical line is generated.

Here is some data.

```
data = Table[{i, Prime[i]}, {i, 25}];
ListPlot[Tooltip[data, DateString[]]]
```

This generates a graph that when you hover over a data point, the date is displayed.

[image]

How can I generate a plot, that when i hover over the point, a vertical line is generated like in the example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this approach, with `Epilog` or `Prolog`, the line generation is independent of the `Tooltip`:

```
ListPlot[Tooltip[data, DateString[]],
 Epilog -> Dynamic@{Thin,
    Replace[
     MousePosition[
      "Graphics"], {p_?VectorQ :> InfiniteLine[Round@p, {0, 1}],
      None :> Nothing}
     ]}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a start:

```
data = Table[{x, N@Exp[x]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.2}];

ClearAll[annotate]
annotate[set_] := Map[
   Mouseover[Tooltip[Point[#], #], {Point[#], Line[{{#[[1]], 0}, #}]}] &,
   set
 ]

Graphics[
  annotate[data],
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
  Axes -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]
]
```

[image]